# Rewrite DELETE statement into a SELECT statement in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, mysqli

I was trying to rewrite a delete statement into a select statement, but I kept getting errors. Here's the delete statement that I was trying to rewrite:

```
DELETE row1 FROM tableName row1, tableName row2 WHERE (row1.id > row2.id) AND (row1.col1 = row2.col1) AND (row1.col2 = row2.col2)
```

Here's the select statement that I tried to write:

```
SELECT row1 FROM tableName row1, tableName row2 WHERE (row1.id > row2.id) AND (row1.col1 = row2.col1) AND (row1.col2 = row2.col2)
```

^---Yes, that is totally wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: With SELECT, you have to specify what columns you want to select from either or both tables, or put a " * " to indicate all columns, e.g. SELECT * FROM .....

Comment: @DBug Great. Now, if you can just do me the favor of answering the question, I'll up vote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '*' to specify that all columns should be selected, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName row1, tableName row2
  WHERE (row1.id > row2.id) AND (row1.col1 = row2.col1) AND (row1.col2 = row2.col2)
```